# Second router configured as refuses to connect most of the time

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dhcp, wireless-access-point

I have setup a second router as an access point but it has very temperamental wireless connections. Devices either cannot connect at all to the second router (setup on a different channel, and SSID) or take a very long time connect. Wireless connections from the main router are OK connection wise but weak from locations near the second router (hence the need for the access point).

I have not set them up on the same SSID as the second router cause poorer performance of the first router's WiFi Connection.[image: network diagram]

Most of the time, wireless devices cannot connect to `duhamp_bedroom`. It does connect very occasionally but it is almost impossible to reproduce this.

I have disabled DHCP and set an IP address within the subnet of the main router. I can't figure out why it does not connect properly - the signal appears strong (-45dBm). I have followed the settings [here](http://www.tplink.com/ie/article/?faqid=417) to the letter - any ideas?

The precise settings for the routers are as follows.

### Main Router

- Virgin Media Super Hub VMDG490
- Normal VLAN interface, default routing settings
- 2.5G and 5G wifi
- Channel 6
- WPA personal

### Second Router

- TP-Link TD-W8960N
- Connected to first router via ethernet LAN port

**Routing**

- IP Address: 192.168.0.10
- Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
- IGMP Snooping disabled
- DHCP Server disabled
- DHCP Server Relay disabled
- NAT disabled

**WiFi**

- UK selected as location (true location)
- WPS disabled
- WPA2-personal
- WPA Group Rekey Interval: 0
- WPA Encryption enabled
- AP Mode Enabled
- Bridge Restrict disabled
- Channel 1
- Mode: 11BGN
- Bandwidth: 20MHZ
- Control Sideband:Lower
- Fragmentation Threshold:2346
- RTS Threshold:   2347
- DTIM Interval: 1
- Beacon Interval: 100
- Transmit Power:  100%
- WMM(Wi-Fi Multimedia): Disabled

Comment: A LAN port on one router is connected to a LAN port on the other?

Comment: Correct - that is the current configuration. I have updated the description accordingly.

Comment: Then WMM is most likely your problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nonsensical configuration. You've disabled WMM but also told it to support 802.11n which, among other things, requires WMM support. That can't possibly work.